# TypeError: Cannot read property 'Eligible' of undefined

Tags: javascript, typeerror

I have this piece of 1 year old code and need to run it now. 
Any possible guesses are welcomed. Any information will help, thanks.

```
function getPrices(){
  let url = 'https://url/api/Prices/v4?key=' + key;
  var massive;
  let quality = '5';
  request({url:url, json:true},  function(err, res, body){
        if (err) console.log(err);

        massive = body.response.items;

        console.log('Prices received')
        for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i += 1){

          let get_json = other.urltojson(data[i].ApiLink);
          let particle = get_json.particle
          let name = data[i].BuyLink;
              name = name.replace(/(\/Eligible).*/, '');
              name = name.replace(/.*(\/)/, '');
              name = name.replace(/\%20/g, ' ');
              name = name.replace(/\%27/g, '\'')

          let comPrice = massive[name].prices[quality].Eligible.Suitable[definition].value;
          data[i].BuyPrice = comPrice;
        }
      });
}
```

Error log:

```
          let comPrice = massive[name].prices[quality].Eligible.Suitable[definition].value;
                                                       ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'Eligible' of undefined
```

Comment: It seems `massive[name].prices[quality]` has no value. Did you try to debug in Browser-dev-tools?

Comment: What does it give you if you `console.log` `massive[name].prices`?

Comment: I am editing this code in Sublime so I can't really do debug.

Comment: Where do you get the error, then?

Comment: @Victor F { '3': { Eligible: { Suitable: [Array] } },
  '6': { Eligible: { Suitable: [Array], 'Non-Suitable': [Array] } } }

Comment: @Nikolaus I run it with Terminal on Mac

Comment: There are no properties with the key `'5'`, that's why it's undefined

Comment: @Victor F If I   `console.log(massive[name].prices[quality]);` it replies: `undefined`. How to fix this? This value should come from this api right? `https://url/api/Prices/v4?key=`

Comment: I meant the object keys - there are no `'5'`s here: `{ '3': { Eligible: { Suitable: [Array] } }, '6': { Eligible: { Suitable: [Array], 'Non-Suitable': [Array] } } }`

Comment: @VictorF I manually checked the api answer and there are plenty of `"5":{"Eligible":{"Suitable":{` any ideas why my code doesn't see no `'5'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error means that `massive[name].prices[quality]` gives undefined.

I don't know how your data structure is, but it could be that you store your `quality` as a string instead of an integer

EDIT:

It would probably make sense for you to make a fallback if `massive[name].prices[quality]` is `undefined`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Could you please tell how to store `quality` as integer?

Comment: Instead of doing `let quality = '5';`, do `let quality = 5;` (without the quotes around `5`).

Comment: Have you seen my last comment on your question? 'There are no properties with the key '5', that's why it's undefined'

Comment: yeah I did. There are plenty of them in the answer from api but for some reason the code doesn't see any of them